# How can I read from a file generated by CreateProcess?

Tags: file, createprocess

I'm trying to run a matlab file which prints a value in another file and then read that value in my c++ application. My code is:

```
int disponibilitate;
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

LPTSTR szCmdline = _wcsdup(TEXT("\"D:\\Program Files\\Matlab\\bin\\matlab.exe\" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r \"run('C:\\Users\\Lucian\\Desktop\\licenta visual studio\\licenta\\licenta\\simulare.m');exit;\""));

if( !CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))

{
    printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}
    fin.open("simulare_matlab_out.txt");
    fin>>disponibilitate;
    cout<<disponibilitate;
fin.close();
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

simulare_matlab_out.txt is the output file of my matlab application.
After running the c++ project it prints a random value but in the simulare_matlab_out.txt file the value is alright.

!!! I think that my problem is that the program doesn't wait for the Created Process to end and then read from the created file !!!
Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use STDOUT.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdout/

FILE *stream ;
   if((stream = freopen("file.txt", "w", stdout)) == NULL)
      exit(-1);

printf("this is stdout output\n");

stream = freopen("CON", "w", stdout);

printf("And now back to the console once again\n");

Comment: isn't stdout for writing in files?

Comment: I think that my problem is that the program doesn't wait for the Created Process to end and then read from the created file